# spring boot rest for one to many relation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I created spring boot project where I am making rest application. I have used My SQL database and I am using spring data. There is one method which adds orders based on customer id. So I am not able to figure out it will work based on spring data query or custom query and how it will be?
I have attached required codes only,

#### Customer.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "cust_ID_PK")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int custIDPK;

@Column(name = "billing_city")
private String billingCity;

@Column(name = "billing_country")
private String billingCountry;

@Column(name = "billing_state")
private String billingState;

@Column(name = "billing_street")
private String billingStreet;

@Column(name = "billing_zip")
private String billingZip;

private String company;

@Column(name = "display_name")
private String displayName;

private String email;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "middle_name")
private String middleName;

@Column(name = "other_details")
private String otherDetails;

@Column(name = "print_on_check_as")
private String printOnCheckAs;

@Column(name = "shipping_city")
private String shippingCity;

@Column(name = "shipping_country")
private String shippingCountry;

@Column(name = "shipping_state")
private String shippingState;

@Column(name = "shipping_street")
private String shippingStreet;

@Column(name = "shipping_zip")
private String shippingZip;

private String suffix;

private String title;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to Order
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Order> orders;

public Customer() {
}

public int getCustIDPK() {
    return this.custIDPK;
}

public void setCustIDPK(int cust_ID_PK) {
    this.custIDPK = cust_ID_PK;
}

public String getBillingCity() {
    return this.billingCity;
}

public void setBillingCity(String billingCity) {
    this.billingCity = billingCity;
}

public String getBillingCountry() {
    return this.billingCountry;
}

public void setBillingCountry(String billingCountry) {
    this.billingCountry = billingCountry;
}

public String getBillingState() {
    return this.billingState;
}

public void setBillingState(String billingState) {
    this.billingState = billingState;
}

public String getBillingStreet() {
    return this.billingStreet;
}

public void setBillingStreet(String billingStreet) {
    this.billingStreet = billingStreet;
}

public String getBillingZip() {
    return this.billingZip;
}

public void setBillingZip(String billingZip) {
    this.billingZip = billingZip;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return this.company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return this.displayName;
}

public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return this.middleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public String getOtherDetails() {
    return this.otherDetails;
}

public void setOtherDetails(String otherDetails) {
    this.otherDetails = otherDetails;
}

public String getPrintOnCheckAs() {
    return this.printOnCheckAs;
}

public void setPrintOnCheckAs(String printOnCheckAs) {
    this.printOnCheckAs = printOnCheckAs;
}

public String getShippingCity() {
    return this.shippingCity;
}

public void setShippingCity(String shippingCity) {
    this.shippingCity = shippingCity;
}

public String getShippingCountry() {
    return this.shippingCountry;
}

public void setShippingCountry(String shippingCountry) {
    this.shippingCountry = shippingCountry;
}

public String getShippingState() {
    return this.shippingState;
}

public void setShippingState(String shippingState) {
    this.shippingState = shippingState;
}

public String getShippingStreet() {
    return this.shippingStreet;
}

public void setShippingStreet(String shippingStreet) {
    this.shippingStreet = shippingStreet;
}

public String getShippingZip() {
    return this.shippingZip;
}

public void setShippingZip(String shippingZip) {
    this.shippingZip = shippingZip;
}

public String getSuffix() {
    return this.suffix;
}

public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
    this.suffix = suffix;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public List<Order> getOrders() {
    return this.orders;
}

public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
}

public Order addOrder(Order order) {
    getOrders().add(order);
    order.setCustomer(this);

    return order;
}

public Order removeOrder(Order order) {
    getOrders().remove(order);
    order.setCustomer(null);

    return order;
}

}
```

#### Order.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@NamedQuery(name = "Order.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Order o")
public class Order implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "order_ID_PK")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int order_ID_PK;

@Column(name = "custom_message")
private String customMessage;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "delivery_due_date")
private Date deliveryDueDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "invoice_creation_date")
private Date invoiceCreationDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "payment_due_date")
private Date paymentDueDate;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cust_ID_FK")
private Customer customer;

// bi-directional many-to-many association to Product
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orders")
private List<Product> products;

public Order() {
}

public int getOrder_ID_PK() {
    return this.order_ID_PK;
}

public void setOrder_ID_PK(int order_ID_PK) {
    this.order_ID_PK = order_ID_PK;
}

public String getCustomMessage() {
    return this.customMessage;
}

public void setCustomMessage(String customMessage) {
    this.customMessage = customMessage;
}

public Date getDeliveryDueDate() {
    return this.deliveryDueDate;
}

public void setDeliveryDueDate(Date deliveryDueDate) {
    this.deliveryDueDate = deliveryDueDate;
}

public Date getInvoiceCreationDate() {
    return this.invoiceCreationDate;
}

public void setInvoiceCreationDate(Date invoiceCreationDate) {
    this.invoiceCreationDate = invoiceCreationDate;
}

public Date getPaymentDueDate() {
    return this.paymentDueDate;
}

public void setPaymentDueDate(Date paymentDueDate) {
    this.paymentDueDate = paymentDueDate;
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return this.customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return this.products;
}

public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

}
```

#### OrderOperation.java

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.model.Order;

public interface OrderOperation extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

@Query("SELECT c.orders FROM Customer c where c.custIDPK = :id")
public List<Order> findOrderbyID(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

#### CustomerController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

@Autowired
ICutomerService customerDAO;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllCustomer() {
    return new ResponseEntity(customerDAO.getAllCustomer(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{CustomerById}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
public Customer getCustomerbyId(@PathVariable("CustomerById") String cid) {
    return customerDAO.findCustomerById(Integer.parseInt(cid));
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@RequestMapping(value = "{CustomerById}/order", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllOrder(@PathVariable("CustomerById") String cid) {
    return new ResponseEntity(customerDAO.getOrdersbyId(Integer.parseInt(cid)), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@RequestMapping(value = "order/{CustomerById}/product", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
        "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllProduct(@PathVariable("CustomerById") String cid) {
    return new ResponseEntity(customerDAO.getProductsById(Integer.parseInt(cid)), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer c) {
    boolean flag = customerDAO.addCustomer(c);
    if (flag)
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{CustomerById}/orders", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addOrders(@PathVariable("CustomerById") String cid, @RequestBody Order c) {
    // c.getCustomer().setCustIDPK(Integer.parseInt(cid));
    boolean flag = customerDAO.addOrder(c);
    if (flag) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
}
```

How should I design this addOrders method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data then you will need to create a CrudRepository for each table you which to access.  The CrudRepository allows you to easily manipulate data in your table using standard ORM practices.  [Here is a link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) with more details.

For more detailed info on how to use Spring Data check out [this wonderful guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).  This guide has become indispensable when working with Spring Data.

Comment: I have created jpaRepositry instead of crudrepository so I can get use some jpa function but I am not figuring out how to add orders using that

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to this but i have used below approach so hope it helps you.  The @Query annotation allows to execute native queries by setting the nativeQuery flag to true.

```
@Query(value = "select o.* from customer c inner join order o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id where o. = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

Please write sql according to your requirement.

Comment: this one is for  select values from the database but I already did that
I have created customers and I want to add orders so it 'll insert query but I don't know how it works and how to implement